# Interactive Window fails to execute when referencing functions across multiple files

Tags: f#

How can I successfully use the Interactive Window within F# when I reference functions across multiple files.

NOTE:

My solution builds. However, when I attempt to execute logic via the Interactive Window, I receive the following error:

> The namespace or module 'Deck' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You can use `#r` to reference an assembly, or `#load` to load another F# script file (`.fsx`).

It's all described in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx).

Comment: In VisualStudio you can also right-click the project and "Send its output to interactive"

Comment: Indeed, and that's also possible to do with project dependencies. That's Visual-Studio specific, though.